Can I use academic tag for designing lesson questions?
I want to design an app for learning Chinese and when I come across a conundrum, such as the order of words are best learned, could I ask it in the academic tag or is there another tag that is better suited for it?
It seems that currently the academic tag is mostly used from a student's perspective.

Yes, that's the use of it. If you want to ask from a teacher's perspective then use the teaching-methodstag.
Make sure that your question fits the guidelines (no opinion-based, no lists, and so on).
